# showing init.d script echo on console

Tags: bash, echo

I have a bash script within /etc/init.d in a kali2016.1 box that executes some actions. My issue is the following: when executing the script as `./script` {start|stop|restart|}, the output of echo shows on the console. When I run it as `service script` {start|stop|restart|*}, however, it logs the echo output in /var/log/daemon.log instead. How can I change this behavior so that, when executing it as service, it continues to log but also shows the echo output on console? Covering the basics, it goes as follows:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    case "$1" in
      start)
        echo "start"
      ;;
      stop)
        echo "stop"
      ;;
      restart)
        echo "restart"
      ;;
      *)
        echo "usage {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
      ;;
    esac
    exit 0
```

Comment: to run it as a daemon, I used `update-rc.d script defaults`

Answer (score 3):

You can `echo "foo" > /dev/console`.

When `stdout` is connected to your terminal you see the output.  Based on your description, the `service` command is redirecting/capturing `stdout` and sending it to syslog.

Have a look at `service` - it's probably a shell script, so you can see what's happening.

FWIW, on most distributions, including CentOS7 and AWS Linux, the `service` script does not change `stdout`.